# tsql populate xml tag when there is no data

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

Is there a way to generate the xml tag when there is no data retrieved for that row?

For example:

```
Select
   firstname,
   middlename,
   lastname
from 
   Names
for xml path('name'), type)
```

Outputs:

```
<name>
   <firstname>John</firstname>
   <middlename>Jim</middlename>
   <lastname>Smith</lastname>
</name>
```

But if there is no middle name it skips that row in the xml.

```
<name>
   <firstname>Jane</firstname>
   <lastname>Smith</lastname>
</name>
```

I'm looking for this output if there is no data for middle name:

```
<name>
   <firstname>Jane</firstname>
   <middlename />
   <lastname>Smith</lastname>
</name>
```

Can this be achieved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    FirstName, 
    MiddleName = ISNULL(MiddleName, ''),
    LastName
FROM    
    @input
FOR XML PATH('name')
```

which gives you

```
<name>
  <FirstName>John</FirstName>
  <MiddleName></MiddleName>
  <LastName>Smith</LastName>
</name>
```

Comment: Of course than you can't tell the difference between Null and an empty string. If that's important you can use [XSINIL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522519.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `XSNIL` like this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
     [FirstName] NVARCHAR(32)
    ,[MiddleName] NVARCHAR(32)
    ,[LastName] NVARCHAR(32)
)

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([FirstName], [MiddleName], [LastName])
VALUES ('John','Smith','Tomas')
      ,('John',NULL,'Tomas')
      ,('John',NULL,NULL)
      ,(NULL,'Smith','Tomas')

SELECT [FirstName]
      ,[MiddleName]
      ,[LastName]
FROM @DataSource
FOR XML PATH('NAME'), ELEMENTS XSINIL, TYPE
```